# Custom title page for each part with scrreprt class

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I'm currently "compiling" a document (scrreprt) which includes many chapters from various other documents.

I want to group these chapters into parts but instead of the titlepage generated by the part-command I want to use the title pages from the subdocuments.

I already managed the including part. Now I wan't to remove the part-pages without destroying things like the page-numbering.

Is there a way to let the parts only appear in the TOC?

```
\part{Architektur} %For the entry in TOC
\includepdf{architecture.pdf} %This includes my titlepage
\input{architecture/deployment} % The actual content of the subdocument
\input{some/more/chapters}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure; you can use the `addtotoc=` option for `\includepdf`; something like

```
\includepdf[addtotoc={1,part,-1,Architektur,prt:arc}]{architecture.pdf}
```

Of course, you can now remove the `\part{Architektur}` command from your document.